# AWS: Understanding Response Times and ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, load-balancing

I'm attempting to profile some API requests for my application in an effort to isolate any potential bottlenecks.  However, I'm seeing a slight discrepancy in one portion of my logging, so I'm trying to make sure I'm not missing anything.

**The Basic Setup**

- AWS Classic ELB (cross zone enabled)
- balances to 2 AWS t2.micro instances (Staging servers)
- The ec2 boxes are running PHP 7.1 and Nginx.
- There's an SSL Certificate but it terminates at the ELB.  So the ELB is connecting to the backend instances via http on Port 80
- The instances are in a private subnet and are connected to the internet via a NAT Gateway

**Gathering Data**

1. I have requests times being logged within the application itself, which are being sent to Loggly (So once the request hits the application code, we get a start time, and once the response has been sent the application, we get an end time)
2. AWS ELB Access Logs
3. CURL requests to a given endpoint with `total_time` enabled

**The Results (for a given endpoint)**

1. Application Request Time

   - I'm seeing Application request times of **0.05-0.08** seconds. This is the data being send to Loggly
2. AWS ELB Access Logs

   - These logs provide 3 numbers:

     - Request Processing Time: **0.00004 seconds**
     - Backend Processing Time: **0.05 - 0.09 seconds**
     - Response Processing Time: **0.00004 seconds**
3. CURL

   - Now, running a CURL command that looks roughly like this:

`curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null www.google.com`

I'm getting `total_time` results of anywhere from: **~ 0.17 - .5 seconds**

So, it seems that the Application logs and the ELB Access Logs show similar results.  However, it seems that the overall request time via CURL, can be **~ 3x - 6x slower**

If that's the case, what might cause this?  My first thought is that it's taking time to connect to the ELB, or maybe we're getting held up on the DNS resolution.

I then tried some basic tests with Apache Benchmark, and that seems to confirm some sort of connection issue.  The connection results are **~ 0.07  - 0.5 seconds **

However, because those times don't show up in the AWS ELB Access Logs, I'm led to believe this is something to do with DNS resolution?  If so, how might I investigate this further?

Currently, my domain is registered on LiquidWeb and has a CNAME record which points to the ELB DNS name provided by AWS

Comment: I don't think you actually *have* an issue.  Starting the curl process and resolving DNS both take a little time, but setting up a TCP connection, negotiating TLS over it, then sending an HTTP request and receiving the response all require a number of round trips, many of which may be avoidable in the real world becauae of connection reuse by the browser.  Are you testing remotely, or from inside EC2?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks Michael. I'm curling remotely.  I guess I read about people striving for 100ms response times, but even on the endpoints where I have the least processing (50ms application time) I'm still get 3-6x higher response times. Was also wondering if there were some keep-alive settings I may be missing

Comment: Keep-alive is automatic on ELB.  Try timing `curl [options] https://... https://... https://...` repeating the same URL multiple times on the command line. I *think* this prompts curl to load them sequentially and it will reuse the connection.  Remove -s and add -v.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yeah i tried that with Apache Benchmark, and if I use -k, it uses the same connection, and the connect-time becomes mostly 0ms.  So it seems thats working.  

So in general everything seems as it should?